# Ubuntu Wont Uninstall On My Windows 8.1 Pro With Uefi! Usb Stick|

Tags: usb, uefi, system-installation

I can't Install Ubuntu 12.04.3 to my notebook PC. I've tried everything from USB Drives to CD/DVD. I Also Have UEFI and here are my system info:

Windows Edition: Windows 8.1 Pro

```
Manufacturer: TOSHIBA (Leading Innovation)
Model: Satellite C55-A
Processer: Intel (R) Celeron(R) CPU 1037U @ 1.80GHz
Installed Memory(RAM) 4.00GB (3.88 Usable)
System Type: 64x Bit Operating System, 64x Based Processer
No Pen And Touch Available.
```

Comment: are you trying to uninstall what?

Comment: The title says Un-install, the body says install. What do you want to do? In both cases the question has been answered before.

Answer (score 2):

You must install 13.10 to support uefi, burn the iso of 13.10 to a USB and then try the installation again, if you can´t still do it I suggest to go to the BIOS options on the computer and enable the legacy boot and not only UEFI boot, hope it helped!

Comment: Yep, i remember reading somewhere when it came out, this is when the EFI support started